# Chrome window.print() opening takes too long time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I have modal dialog, with some text that should be printed, and print link. So when I press print, it takes me about 30 sec to open preview dialog in chrome(firefox, safari, ie are fine). What is the reason of that?

dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="to_print_data">
    My data to print!!!!!
    </div>
    Click <a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;"> here</a>
</div> 

    <style>
    @media print {
      body * {
        visibility:hidden;
      }

    #to_print_data, #to_print_data * {
        visibility:visible;
      }
      #to_print_data {
        position:absolute;
        left:0!important;
        top:0!important;
        border:0!important;
        font-size:16px!important;
      }
    }
    </style>
```

**UPDATE:**

I found cause, in the background running some script, that makes post request, and request have pending status about 30 sec, after it finished print-dialogue appears. How to prevent this behavior, when print waiting for post request to finish, without removing script?

Comment: Could be specific to your particular instance of Chrome (too many extensions loaded or something). What happens if you try it in incognito mode?

Comment: If using chrome, use the network panel under your developer tools to see what which resources are causing a delay in your loading process.

Comment: @RobGrzyb version is Version 25.0.1364.172 m; and all extension are disabled

Comment: @blachawk network panel how i understand show request, so nothing there

Comment: @RobGrzyb in incognito mode i have the same behavior...

Comment: Seems to run fine for me in same version of Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/GZupE/

Comment: Are you signed into Chrome, and if so, are you also connected to Google Cloud Print?

Comment: @RobGrzyb your link working for me too, it's not full code I use control.modal to display dialog http://code.google.com/p/infoscoop/source/browse/trunk/src/main/web/js/lib/control.modal.js?r=370

Comment: @Noyo yes i am signed, but Google Cloud Print is disabled

Comment: Is "Google Drive" your default printer? Also, if this is happening in other code, please post a fiddle that contains a working example that uses the actual code. We cannot troubleshoot behavior we cannot reproduce. :]

Comment: @Noyo I have this error in all chrome browsers, so some code cause this. I can't provide code because I am using Magento cms, and it have some libraries based on prototype + scriptaculous for modal dialogs. May be you know what presumably can cause this problem?

Comment: Also I noticed that when I press Ctrl+P it loads immediately without delay.

Comment: I found cause, in the background running some extension, that makes post request, and request have pending status about 30 sec, after it finished print-dialogue appears. How to prevent this behaviour, when print waiting for post request to finish, without unistalling extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause. If in the background is running some extension, that makes post request. And this request have pending status about 30 sec. Only after it finishes print-dialogue appears. So pending request blocks print dialogue to be opened

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wouldn't even print at all until I refreshed the page, as described here: [Chrome: window.print() print dialogue opens only after page reload (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622626/chrome-window-print-print-dialogue-opens-only-after-page-reload-javascript).

@noypiscripter's answer solved it for me:

```
function printPage() {
    window.print();

    //workaround for Chrome bug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141633
    if (window.stop) {
        location.reload(); //triggering unload (e.g. reloading the page) makes the print dialog appear
        window.stop(); //immediately stop reloading
    }
    return false;
}
```